# Is ending up in hell at some point in time inevitable for those beings who are not Stream-Entrants?

Tags: philosophy, nirvana, hells

I have seen this a few times in various places, although I haven't read it in any suttas, but I am guessing there might be some that talk about this.

Answer (score 2):

The 4th jhāna brahma and above have a [long enough age](https://suttacentral.net/vb18/en/thittila#pts-cs1022) to meet more than 1 buddha, they are not going to hell until they die. So buddha can't say "If you do not enlighten by my teaching, you are going to hell soon".

However, most being are going to hell, included dead brahma, by Sutta. Saṃ. Ma. [Āmakadhaññapeyyāle](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=19&A=11397&eng=accesstoinsight_than):

> "In the same way, monks, few are the beings who, on passing away from
>   the human realm, are reborn among human beings. Far more are the
>   beings who, on passing away from the human realm, are reborn in the
>   animal womb... in the domain of the hungry ghosts.
>
> ... "In the same way, monks, few are the beings who, on passing away
>   from the human realm, are reborn among devas. Far more are the beings
>   who, on passing away from the human realm, are reborn in hell... in
>   the animal womb... in the domain of the hungry ghosts.
>
> ... "In the same way, monks, few are the beings who, on passing away
>   from the deva realm, are reborn among devas. Far more are the beings
>   who, on passing away from the deva realm, are reborn in hell... in the
>   animal womb... in the domain of the hungry ghosts.
>
> ... "In the same way, monks, few are the beings who, on passing away
>   from the deva realm, are reborn among human beings. Far more are the
>   beings who, on passing away from the deva realm, are reborn in hell...
>   in the animal womb... in the domain of the hungry ghosts.
>
> "Therefore **your duty is the contemplation**, 'This is stress... This is
>   the origination of stress... This is the cessation of stress.' Your
>   duty is the contemplation, 'This is the path of practice leading to
>   the cessation of stress.'"

Hurry up.

Comment: Very good quote! These suttas also say "animals" (such as Angulimala) can realise the Four Noble Truths; such as in this video made in Thailand: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNzrKAzxipY

Comment: Why hurry up? The more you hurry, the more you crave. Seeing the four noble truths should happen in a moment.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu the [buddha said](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=23&A=4888&eng=metta_e&eng=suttacentral) "When you’ve gained the human state, and the true teaching has been proclaimed, **if you don’t seize the moment**, it’ll pass you by."

Comment: Another the [buddha said](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka2/v.php?B=12&A=1754&Z=2150&eng=accesstoinsight_than) that many people have to use **more than a moment to practice**: "Now, if anyone would develop these four frames of reference in this way for seven years, one of two fruits can be expected for him: either gnosis right here & now, or — if there be any remnant of clinging/sustenance — non-return."

Comment: @Dhammadhatu So, why you try to lie us about the real tipitaka? Why Tipitaka say " more than a moment" but you say "in a moment". Why Buddha cheer us to practice hard, but you deny us to hurry to practice? Why you try to cut some part of Tipitaka off and distort it?

Comment: Sorry but practise in described in MN 131. It does not hurry. It is in the present moment.  Also, practise has Noble Fruit - the realisation of emptiness (sunnata).

Comment: It is right to say "the buddha teach to practice at every moment", but it is wrong to say "practice at every moment can't call 'hurry up'". **When one wastes the moments to chatter, we call him "he hesitates". And when that one changes his behaviour to do all moments for achieving the objective, we call him "he hurry up".**

Comment: How is angulimala an animal? He was born in the human realm

Comment: @Dhammadhatu [Vinaya Pitaka](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=4&A=3602&eng=metta_e) denies ordaining of an animal ‘Let an animal, O bhikkhus, that has not received the upasampadā ordination, not receive it; if it has received it, let it be expelled (from the fraternity).’ Angulimala was a human, so he could ordain as a monk at the end of MN [Aṅgulimālasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=13&item=521&items=14&eng=accesstoinsight_than).

Answer (score 1):

What it says is there is assurance no hell for the stream entrants.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that everyone who hadn't reached the stream is destined for the hell realm. The determinants for one entering the hell realm lie in the mechanism of karma or the actions one performs.

One might find insight to the hell realm by discerning one's own changing psychological states throughout ones lifetime.

As for the hell realm beyond ones current physical form, I haven't a clue but if you can see it in situations of your current life and in others lives one can deduce that the karmic thought stream continues on through into another six sense doors. Likewise for good karma.

Answer (score 1):

> .. [Perception](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn25/sn25.006.than_en.html) of ideas is inconstant, changeable, alterable. One who has conviction & belief ... one who, after pondering with a modicum of discernment... one who knows and sees ...

There are/doing 3 kinds of people  who by certain qualities are no more capable to fall into lower states , not only those having reached the path by seeing for themselves.

[Entering](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/index_en.html#sn25)
-  [The Eye](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn25/sn25.001.than_en.html)
- [Forms](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn25/sn25.002.than_en.html)
- ...
- [Properties](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn25/sn25.009.than_en.html)
- [Aggregates](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn25/sn25.010.than_en.html)

*[Note: this gift is not thought for any commercial purpose, trade, stake and exchange for wordily gain as well not for inattentive people who just seek for entertainment]*

Answer (score 1):

there is a famous sutta where an actor loved his idea that he is a good person, as usual with puthujjanas, they always build a view where entertainment is beneficial to people, where sensual pleasures, delight, enjoyment are skillful, whereas the buddha spend his time stating the opposite

> "Worthless man, from whom have you understood that Dhamma taught by me
>   in such a way? Worthless man, haven't I in many ways described
>   obstructive acts? And when indulged in they are genuine obstructions.
>   I have said that sensual pleasures are of little satisfaction, much
>   stress, much despair, & greater drawbacks. I have compared sensual
>   pleasures to a chain of bones: of much stress, much despair, & greater
>   drawbacks. I have compared sensual pleasures to a lump of flesh... a
>   grass torch... a pit of glowing embers... a dream... borrowed goods...
>   the fruits of a tree... a butcher's ax and chopping block... swords
>   and spears... a snake's head: of much stress, much despair, & greater
>   drawbacks. But you, worthless man, through your own wrong grasp [of
>   the Dhamma], have both misrepresented us as well as injuring yourself
>   and accumulating much demerit for yourself, for that will lead to your
>   long-term harm & suffering."[2]
>   https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.022.than.html

then the buddha states

> Now, there are two destinations for a person with wrong view, I tell
>   you: either hell or the animal womb."

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.002.than.html

Of course, puthujjanas can go to numerous higher realms before going to ''either hell or the animal womb'', like the puthujjanas who do only metta, 
https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.037.than.html

But puthujjanas who practice metta, karuna, and so on after avoiding  being intoxicated & heedless manage to stop rebirth in some higher realm.
The Pratice of sense restrain plus the 4 metta, karuna , mudita, uppeka is the slowest path, since rebirth is not stopped ''in this very life'', but only in the next one.

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an07/an07.049.than.html

as usual, wrong view springs from clinging to the five aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

MN 117 says there is two sorts of right view: (i) Noble and (ii) ordinary.

In ordinary right view, those who follow the five precepts and ten wholesome actions will not be reborn in hell. For example:

> *As a result of being endowed with these ten courses of skillful action, [rebirth among] the devas is declared, [rebirth among] human
>   beings is declared — that or any other good destination.*
>
> *AN 10.176*

But in Noble Right View, only those who realise the Four Noble Truths will not be reborn in hell.

> *… the sentient beings who die as humans and are reborn as humans are few, while those who die as humans and are reborn in hell are many …*
>
> *Why is that?*
>
> *It’s because they haven’t seen the four noble truths.*
>
> [*SN 56.102*](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.102/en/sujato)

The Buddha provided different teachings for different people. Per MN 117, the doctrine of "kamma & rebirth" is not for those seeking the Noble Path (of abandoning self-views) and is not a factor of the Noble Path. Its mostly for householders, as follows:

> *The ascetics and brahmans thus ministered to as the Zenith by a householder show their compassion towards him in six ways:*
>
> *(i) they restrain him from evil, (ii) they persuade him to do good,
>   (iii) they love him with a kind heart, (iv) they make him hear what he
>   has not heard, (v) they clarify what he has already heard, (vi) **they
>   point out the path to a heavenly state**.*
>
> *DN 31*